# Zweimal "dem" in "vor dem und nach dem 9. November 1989"

Tags: usage, article

Aus *Der Spiegel*:

> *Die* Mauer eingerannt. Warum ist immer nur von der einen Mauer die Rede? Es gab Hunderte Mauern, die zum Einstürzen gebracht werden mussten, **vor dem und nach dem 9. November 1989**.

Warum wird **dem** zweimal in diesem Satz benutzt? Wäre es ungrammatisch

> vor und nach dem 9. November 1989

zu schreiben? Wenn beide richtig sind, gibt es Unterschiede mit der Konnotation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nein, das ist nur ein stilistischer Unterschied. Die Konstruktion ohne Wiederholung des Artikels ist wahrscheinlich sogar häufiger, jedenfalls aber nicht falsch.

Comment: Die Konstruktion ohne Wiederholung schiene mir auch eleganter.